# Capture all page load packets selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, wireshark, pyshark

I want to capture all packets related to a page loading when using
`selenium`. I'm collecting the timestamps myself and comparing them to the packets data from `wireshark.` When I do this it shows me the start time but not the end time.

Here is my code:

```
class Test():
    def packet_trace(self,url):
        domain = url.split('.')[0]
        path = '/path/to/save'
        packet_details_path = os.path.join(path, domain + '.pcap')
        self.capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='enp0s25', output_file=packet_details_path)
        for packet in self.capture.sniff_continuously(packet_count=self.network_trace):
            print(packet)

    def connection_firefox(self):
        url_list = ['facebook.com','apple.com','google.com']
        for url in self.url_list:
            try:
                full_url = 'https://' + url
                domain = url.split('.')[0]
                driver = webdriver.Firefox()

                try:
                    driver.set_page_load_timeout(self.timeout)
                    self.packet_trace(url)
                    path_trace_details = '/path/to/save'
                    start_time = time.time()
                    driver.get(full_url)   
                    end_time = time.time()
                    total_time = end_time - start_time
                    packet_info_path = os.path.join(path_trace_details, domain + '_info.txt')
                    with codecs.open(packet_info_path, 'w+' , 'utf-8') as write_info:
                        write_info.write(f'url:: {full_url} \nstart_time:: {start_time}\n entry_node:: {circuit_entry_node} \nend_time:: {end_time} \ntotal_time:: {total_time}')
                except TimeoutException as e:
                    path = '/path/to/save'
                    write_error = os.path.join(path, 'timeout_in_' + domain + '.txt')
                    write_mode = codecs.open(write_error, 'w+' , 'utf-8')
                    write_mode.write(f'url:: {full_url} \n time out error:: {e} \n -----------------------------------------------')
                    driver.close()
                    continue

            except Error as e:
                path = '/path/to/save'
                write_error = os.path.join(path, domain + '.txt')
                write_mode = codecs.open(write_error, 'w+' , 'utf-8')
                write_mode.write.write(f'url:: {full_url} \n error:: {e} \n -----------------------------------------------')
                driver.close()
                continue

test = Test()
test.connection_firefox()
```

I don't know why it's working like this. once it reach to **self.packet_trace(url)** the code finish running the function. and I want to run the capturing packet section until a page completely load.

Comment: How is this question different from from your other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74663021/how-to-start-capture-packet-after-before-getting-the-url-selenium)?

Comment: No one answer this question and i found the solution for this. then i was have issue with the output I want to get. thats why post that one